# How does this recursive method print 3 times instead of just exiting?

Tags: java, recursion

```
public static void foo(int n) {

    if(n > 0) {
        if(n % 2 == 0) {
            foo(n - 3); 
        } else {
            foo(n - 1); 
        }
    }

    System.out.println(n); 
}
```

I'm not understanding the recursive method here. I see how it would print -1, but I'm not understanding how it would print "-1 2 3". Any help would be appreciated.

The method was called by `foo(3)`

Comment: You did not show how it was invoked. What as the value of the parameter?

Comment: Did you step through it in your IDE debugger? That would be easier and faster than asking here, and you would actually learn something.

Comment: Why wouldn't it print 3 times?

Comment: I did, I used pythontutor.com to visualize it, but I don't get why after it prints -1, it goes back to the "n % 2" line

Comment: Actually you could simply run it in a debugger and you will see how the code flows.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is the process..

```
foo(3) --> foo(2)
//because  (3 % 2 != 0)

foo(2) --> foo(-1)
//because  (2 % 2 == 0)

foo(-1) --> print -1
//because (-1 < 0)  
//goes back & continue from last point where this method is called

print 2, then exit method
//goes back & continue from last point where this method is called

print 3, then exit method
//goes back & continue from last point where this method is called

back to main()
```

> I did, I used pythontutor.com to visualize it, but I don't get why after it prints -1, it goes back to the "n % 2" line

It still continue to prints because after printing `-1`, even though it exits the method which prints -1, but it returns and continue from where foo(-1) was called. It continues from there..

Answer (score 1):

Recursive method are working continuesly by requesting same methods it self.
In your Code when you request `foo (3);`

Time 1 : `3%2=1` so this will request `ELSE` part
  Then `foo (3-1)` = `foo (2);` will be called.
Time 2 : `2%2=0` so this will request `IF` part
  Then `foo (2-3)` = `foo (-1)` will be called.
Time 3 : `-1 > 0 = False` So Print Method will be called.

System will print `-1`. 
  Time 3 function will be ended and goes to Time 2 function

System will print `2`
  Time 2 function will be ended and goes to Time 1 function

System will print `3`.

So the output 
`-1 2 3`